# Add and remove class for selected tab panels

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, addclass, removeclass

I need to add the 'selectedTab' class and remove the 'notSelectedTab' class to the clicked tab and add the 'notSelectedTab' class to all the other tabbed panels. Currently, the script gives all clicked tabs the 'selectedTab' class, I would appreciate steering me in the right direction. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

```
<style>
/*Selected Tab*/
.selectedTab {
    background-color:#CBD8E1;;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(69, 145, 193);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(69, 145, 193);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(69, 145, 193);
    border-bottom: nonet;
    color: rgb(69, 145, 193);
    line-height: 0.5em;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
/*Non-Selected Tab*/
.notSelectedTab {
    border: 1px solid rgb(69, 145, 193);
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: rgb(69, 145, 193);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    line-height: 0.5em;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
.notSelectedTab:hover {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgb(69, 145, 193);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
</style>


<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
$('ul.nav li a').click(
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
    $(this).find('.selectedTab').removeClass('selectedTab').addClass('notSelectedTab');
    $(this).addClass('selectedTab').removeClass('notSelectedTab');
});

});</script>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li><a class="selectedTab" href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="notSelectedTab" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
   <li><a class="notSelectedTab" href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
   <li><a class="notSelectedTab" href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with you code is that you are not getting the common parent between all of your anchors when removing the class. Try to use `.closest()` before using find :

```
$('ul.nav li a').click(
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
    $(this).closest('.nav').find('.selectedTab').removeClass('selectedTab').addClass('notSelectedTab');
    $(this).addClass('selectedTab').removeClass('notSelectedTab');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify it with an `active` class on the `li` tag.

```
<li class="active">...</li>
```

In the script add `active` class to current element and remove `active` class from siblings:

```
$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
```

Comment: this is the most straightforward way to do this type of thing in most cases; you may also find it useful to use the `.not()` method, i.e. `$('ul.nav li).not('active').addClass('inactive');`. I like the above solution the best though, as it is minimal code, and easy to expand.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selector for adding `notSelectedTab` class to previously selected element. use :

```
$('ul.nav li a').click(
function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
 e.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
 $('.selectedTab').removeClass('selectedTab').addClass('notSelectedTab');
 $(this).addClass('selectedTab').removeClass('notSelectedTab');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p6p1ezL7/)**

Comment: This script works great for what I asked for, now I notice that the div > class='tab-content' is not changing content with the selected tab. I don't know how to make it work? Should I start a new post?

Comment: correction ... it's the div class="tab-pane active"  that isn't switching with the related tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
$('ul.nav li a').click(
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
    $('.selectedTab').removeClass('selectedTab').addClass('notSelectedTab');
    $(this).addClass('selectedTab').removeClass('notSelectedTab');
});

});</script>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Oops, duplicate answer! Sorry, Milind Anatwar gave the answer first.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
var tabLabels=$("ul li a");
tabLabels.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
    tabLabels.removeClass("selectedTab notSelectedTab").not(this).addClass("notSelectedTab");             
    $(this).addClass("selectedTab");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/5nm4gLce/)